# Sending email from python3.4 using smtplib

Tags: python, python-3.4, smtplib

Hi I am trying to send an email through python. I use this code to send:

```
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host='send.one.com',port=465)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(USER, PASS)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(mailFrom, mailTo, text)
    server.quit()
```

but I get an error on the first line:

```
File "/home/emil/Name_Generator/VoteMail.py", line 69, in sendVoteMail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host='send.one.com',port=465)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 323, in connect
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 376, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Has anyone else tried to connect to one.com smtp server with Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone else that use one.com for your email and you want to connect to theire SMTP server thene I found out that they use SSL, and that was why my code did't work the proper way to do it is as follow:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='send.one.com',port=465)
server.login(USER, PASS)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(mailFrom, mailTo, text)
server.quit()
```